# Can't get ag-grid to display User's Role

Tags: angular, spring, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

This is my first time using ag Grid and I'm trying to display all my user's information in the ag Grid, and I can't get to display each one's role. Roles are stored in an array because each user can get one or more roles. It would be great if you could point out what I have been missing here because I have been stuck for a while now.

so this is my user's model in Angular :

```
import { Role } from "../../accounts-mangament/model/role";

export class UserDisplay {

    id: number;
    name : string ;
    username : string;
    email : string ; 
    roles : Role[];
    isDeactivated : number ;
    createdAt : Date ;
    createdBy : string ;
}
```

and this is the User's Model in SpringBoot

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "username" }), @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email"})})
public class User extends Auditable<String> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String username;
    @NaturalId
    private String email;
    private String password;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
    private int isActive; //now   
    private String confirmationToken;
    private String resetToken;
    private int isDeactivated;
 }
```

My angular's UserService

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserServiceService {

  private baseURL = environment.apiUrl ;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  getUserList () : Observable <UserDisplay[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseURL}api/USERS`);
  }
}
```

My Component :

```
columnDefs = [
    
    {  headerName: 'Name', field: 'name',width: 200, sortable: true, filter: true, checkboxSelection: checkboxSelection, headerCheckboxSelection: headerCheckboxSelection },
    {  headerName: 'UserName', field: 'username', width: 200, sortable: true, filter: true },
    {  headerName: 'Address mail', field: 'email' ,width: 200, sortable: true, filter: true },
    {  headerName: 'Account Status', field: 'isDeactivated', width: 150,sortable: true, filter: true ,editable: true,  cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: { values: accountstatus },
       filterParams: { valueFormatter: function (params) { return lookupValue(accountstatusMappings, params.value);}, },
       valueFormatter: function (params) { return lookupValue(accountstatusMappings, params.value);},
    },
    {  headerName: 'Global Role', field: 'roles', width: 150,sortable: true, filter: true ,editable: true,  cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: { values: role },
       filterParams: { valueFormatter: function (params) { return lookupValue(roleMappings, params.value);}, },
       valueFormatter: function (params) { return lookupValue(roleMappings, params.value);},
    },
    {  headerName: 'Creation Date', field: 'createdAt', width: 250, sortable: true, filter: true },
    {  headerName: 'Created By', field: 'createdBy', width: 150, sortable: true, filter: true }    
  ];

  rowData : UserDisplay [] ;
...
 ngOnInit(): void {

    this.userServ.getUserList().subscribe(
      data => { this.rowData = data;
      console.log("data",this.rowData);
    },
      error => console.error(error));

  }
....
```

[and this is what I get as an output for the Role part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPvms.png)

[and this is the data structure of User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypNvJ.png)

For now, I just Added, this code to display the first assigned role :

> valueGetter: (params) => params.data.roles[0].name

so the code became :

```
 columnDefs = [

....
{  headerName: 'Global Role', field: 'roles', valueGetter: (params) => params.data.roles[0].name ,width: 150,sortable: true, filter: true ,editable: true,  cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: { values: role },
   filterParams: { valueFormatter: function (params) { return lookupValue(roleMappings, params.value);}, },
   valueFormatter: function (params) { return lookupValue(roleMappings, params.value);},
},
...  ];
```

[display became like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0KmH.png)

Comment: what is lookupValue?

Answer (score 0):

you can show the whole list by formatting it with valuegetter.

```
valueGetter: (params) => params.data.roles.join()
```

I think set column filter would be more appropriate to filter this column.

> https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/filter-set/